# Ways of making 10 letter combinations out of 3 given letters

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Find the number of 10 letter combinations from ${a, b, c}$ that contain:

1. At least one of each letter
2. At least two of each letter
3. At least one A, two Bs, three Cs
4. Any number of each letter

(Also repetition is allowed)

For number 1 I think that the answer is $\binom{9}{2}$, since there's n-1 places that I can place a bar from stars&bars.
For number 2 though I'm not sure how I can apply this in order to place the bars so that I get at least 2 of each element $a,b,c$.

Edit 2: I did some thinking about question 2 and I think I might have an answer which is correct. Since I need at least 2 of each letter I decided to group 1 of $AA, BB, CC$ so that $AA$ was one object meaning that now in total I had 7 objects. Which then means that I would have $\binom{6}{2}$ places to divide this group up. Please let me know if this approach is correct. Or if I've made a mistake. Thank you.

Comment: Use [Stars and Bars](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Comment: Hi just making sure but for number 1 would this simply mean that the answer is $\binom{9}{2}$?

Comment: @IKnowNothing, $\binom{9}{2}=36$ is number of strings with distinct frequencies of $a,b,c$. Were you simply looking for this, or do you have to consider permutations of $a,b,c$ in the strings also? That would be much bigger number.

Comment: The question asked for combinations so I think that 36 would be sufficient, thank you. For the following question I'm not sure how to proceed though. Since when I want at least 2 of each element I don't know how this would affect the number of places that I can place a bar. I think it might be $\binom{7}{2}$ but I'm not really sure here. Since I know I wouldn't be able to put a bar between star 1,2 and 9,10. But I don't know how to restrict it so that I can't place 2 bars next to each other within the remaining 7 slots that I can place them, I think it might be less than $\binom{7}{2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let frequency of $a,b,c$ be $x,y,z$ respectively. You're looking for integral solutions of following cases :

1. $x \ge 1, y \ge 1, z \ge 1$ and $x+y+z=10$
2. $x \ge 2, y \ge 2, z \ge 2$ and $x+y+z=10$

This is same as $u \ge 1, v \ge 1, w \ge 1$ and $u+v+w=7$

3. $x \ge 1, y \ge 2, z \ge 3$ and $x+y+z=10$

This is same as $x \ge 1, p \ge 1, q \ge 1$ and $x+p+q=7$

4. $x \ge 0, y \ge 0, z \ge 0$ and $x+y+z=10$

> Hence answers would be $\binom{9}{2}, \binom{6}{2},\binom{6}{2}, \binom{12}{2}$ respectively.

Comment: Hi I think I finally understand how to do it! Thank you so much for your help. I did make an edit pretty much exactly the same time as your reply saying how I did it. But I prefer the method you used so I'll probably use this in future, thank you so much. For the last one though I got $\binom{12}{2}$ instead rather than $3^{10}$

Comment: I saw your edit just now. It is also correct.

Answer (score -1):

For (1), start with "abc" so that you have fulfilled  the "at least one of each letter" requirement.  You have 7 letters that can be any of the three "a", "b", or "c" so there are 3^7 possible choices.  For each such 10 letter combination there are 10! possible arrangements of the letters.  There are 10!(3^7) such combinations.

For (2), start with "aabbcc".  There are then 4 letters left so 3^4 possible choices.  Since there are again 10! different arrangements, there are 10!(3^4) such combinations.

For (3), start with "abbccc" and finish in the same way.

For (4), with just 10 letters chosen from "a", "b", and "c", there are 3^10 such combinations.

Comment: Are you sure about 10! ?

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply, however for the first example I'm struggling to see how there would be that many combinations of 3 letters in 10 spaces. Perhaps for permutations but not combinations

Comment: Unfortunately, even for permutations, this answer is not correct for parts 1 through 3.

Comment: To demonstrate that parts 1 through 3 are not correct, for part 4, you have $3^{10}$ permutations where there are no restrictions. For part (1), there is a restriction, and you say the answer is $10!(3^7) = 7936185600 > 3^{10} = 59049$.